# TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I ran:

```py
y_test,y_train,x_test,x_train=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=46)
```

But got:

```
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'NoneType'>
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `x` or `y` is `None`:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_test_split(None, None)
# TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'NoneType'>
```

The message says that the inputs should be some sequence:

```py
train_test_split([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 0])
# [[1, 2], [3], [1, 1], [0]]
```